# Column Color Change issue in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an issue here with a column operation. I have 2 DrillDown s for this particular Table.I have a column which returns 1 (Flag) on a particular date. This is the detailed row.

Now , on top of the flag at the second level i do SUM(Flag) and returns "RED" if it is above 3. Now on the first level I want to create another Background change to "RED" if the value of SUM(Flag) at the second level is >3 or

Change color at the First level, if the textbox color of SUM(Flag) is "RED"

[image: Table Structure]

[image: Grouping]

Can you please help me out on this.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. The expression for the background color should not be directly in the textbox. Go into the Text Box Properties. Go to Fill. Put that expression in Fill color.

Comment: I have tried the below expression as                                                                     = iif(SUM(Fields!Flag.Value,"Fields!EmpID.value")>2,"RED",Nothing), But it gives me an error..."the value expression for the 'TextBox62' has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function. It says that the scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group or name of a dataset or name of a containing data region. "

Comment: The name of your group is not "Fields!EmpID.value". Look near the bottom of the screen, there should be a section called "Row Groups"/"Column Groups". The name of your group will be there, that's what you are referencing.

Comment: Steven, I am really apologize but Like I said the First level Group name is "EmpID" and I put it there it gives the same Problem again and again

Comment: If you still get an error with this there is something else going on: =iif(SUM(Fields!Flag.Value) > 3,"Red",Nothing)

Comment: = iif(SUM(Fields!Flag.Value,"EmpID")>2,"RED",Nothing),,,Not working

Comment: I have got that correct at the SUM(Flag) level,the one beside the empid level

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is add a grouping reference to your SUM expressions. For example:

```
=iif(SUM(Fields!Flag.Value, "FirstLevelGroup") > 3,"Red",Nothing)
```

This allows you to control which scope you are referencing with your sums. Make sure you modify this to match the name of your group, which is at the bottom of the screen. Also make sure you place this expression in BackgroundColor field, not in the textbox itself.

Comment: Can you please explain further, Cause I tried doin this but it gives me an error about the scope not being correct.....

Comment: Make sure to use your current group names in the expression. Posting the error you got may help.

Comment: Warning 1 [rsAggregateOfNonNumericData] The BackgroundColor expression for the text box ‘Textbox2’ uses a numeric aggregate function on data that is not numeric.                                                              Numeric aggregate functions (Sum, Avg, StDev, Var, StDevP, and VarP) can only aggregate numeric data.

Comment: I really apologize steven , but its just not workin..........i have the above expression in the background color section of the textbox, its just throwing me an error.Can you please help me out on this..

Comment: the value expression for the 'TextBox49'  has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function. It says that the scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group or name of a dataset or name of a containing data region.

Comment: A couple of things to check. Open the grouping panel and be sure the group name is the same in both the function and the group panel. Thi must also be entered as a string with ". Also you may need to check of all flag values are in fact values, you may need an iif function to capture any blank cells. Also you cam add a converter to the flag value to ensure that are numeric, eg `Cint(..)`